# Access outside scope when using Class.new

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to somehow access `a` inside the Class.new scope?

```
a = 5
Class.new{ def b; a end }.new.b
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for #<#<Class:0x007fa8b15e9ca8>:0x007fa8b15e9af0>
# :in `b'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even though @MarekLipka answer is correct - it is always risky to change variable scope. This works because each block carries the context it has been created in and hence your local variable `a` suddenly is not that local - it became a 'hidden' global:

```
a = 5
object = Class.new { define_method('b') { a } }.new
object.b #=> 5

a = 4
object.b #=> 4
```

This is naturally useful if you want to pass non-duplicable variable by reference (this actually works very alike javascript closures), however in most of the cases it will introduce extremely hard to debug bugs:

```
a = 5
object = Class.new { define_method('b') { a = a + 1 } }.new
object.b
a #=> 6
```

It is much cleaner to use instance variable instead:

```
a = 5

Class.new do
  def initialize(a)
    @a = a 
  end 

  def b
    @a
  end
end.new(a).b  #=> 5
```

Comment: I lost my spirit before I go further.. But +1 for the explanations. :)

Comment: Of course, it's a class, so just pass the variable into the initializer and make it an instance variable! Brilliant!

Answer (score 7):

You can use `define_method` instead of `def` keyword and pass block to it (block is closure, so it holds reference to `a`):

```
a = 5
Class.new { define_method('b') { a } }.new.b
# => 5
```

Answer (score -1):

you can make 'a' as a global variable

```
$a = 5
Class.new{ def b; $a end }.new.b
```

Comment: Down-vote is mine. I didn't add explanation because Smar did it for me.